# Almacenar un objeto Json, que contenga subobjetos, usando JSONObject Volley

Tags: java, android, json

Necesito guardar el siguiente objeto `Json`, emplando `JSONObject` ( volley).

[image: Obejto Json]

```
{
        "idAsignatura": {
            "idAsignatura": 1,
            "nombreAsignatura": "Cálculo"
        },
        "idEstudiante": {
            "idEstudiante": 1,
            "idUsuario": {
                "emailUsuario": "victoria@sawp.cl",
                "idUsuario": 3,
                "nombreUsuario": "Victoria Martínez",
                "pwdUsuario": "1234",
                "rolUsuario": "Estudiante"
            },
            "matriculado": 1
        },
        "idTareas": 1,
        "nombreTarea": "Series de Fourier",
        "tareaNota": 7
    }
```

Para ello uso el siguiente método:

public void onAgregaTarea(Tareas t) {

```
    final JSONObject jsonObjectU = new JSONObject();
    try{

        jsonObjectU.put("emailUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getEmailUsuario()).
                put("idUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getIdUsario()).
                put("nombreUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getNombreUsuario()).
                put("emailUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getEmailUsuario()).
                put("pdwUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getPwdUsuario()).
                put("rolUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getRolUsuario())  ;

    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    final JSONObject jsonObjectE = new JSONObject();
    try{

        jsonObjectU.put("idEstudiante",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdEstudiante()).
                put("idUsuario",jsonObjectU).
                put("matriculado",t.getIdEstudiante().getMatriculado()) ;

    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    final JSONObject jsonObjectA = new JSONObject();
    try{

        jsonObjectA.put("idAsignatura",t.getIdAsignatura().getIdAsignatura()).put("nombreAsignatura",t.getIdAsignatura().getNomAsiganatura());


    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    final JSONObject jsonObjectT = new JSONObject();
    try{

            jsonObjectT.put("idAsiganatura", jsonObjectA).put("idEstudiante",jsonObjectE)
                .put("nombreTarea", t.getNombreTarea()).put("tareaNota", t.getTareaNota());

    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObjectT,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(ControlTareas.this, "Se envió correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(ControlTareas.this, "Ocurrió un error al enviar la información", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    queue.add(request);

}
```

Pero no me funciona... espero su ayuda. Gracias.

**Implementé dos soluciones, pero ambas me lanzan la misma excepción, ver final:**

**//SOLUCIÓN1:**
 @Override

```
public void onAgregaTarea(Tareas t) {

    final JSONObject jsonObjectU = new JSONObject();
    try{

        jsonObjectU.put("emailUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getEmailUsuario());
        jsonObjectU.put("idUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getIdUsario());
        jsonObjectU.put("nombreUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getNombreUsuario());
        jsonObjectU.put("pwdUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getPwdUsuario());
        jsonObjectU.put("rolUsuario",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getRolUsuario()) ;

    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONArray jsonArrayU = new JSONArray();
    jsonArrayU.put(jsonObjectU);



    final JSONObject jsonObjectE = new JSONObject();
    try{

        jsonObjectE.put("idEstudiante",t.getIdEstudiante().getIdEstudiante());
        jsonObjectE.put("idUsuario",jsonArrayU);
        jsonObjectE.put("matriculado",t.getIdEstudiante().getMatriculado());

    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray jsonArrayE = new JSONArray();
    jsonArrayE.put(jsonObjectE);

    final JSONObject jsonObjectA = new JSONObject();
    try{

        jsonObjectA.put("idAsignatura",t.getIdAsignatura().getIdAsignatura());
        jsonObjectA.put("nombreAsignatura",t.getIdAsignatura().getNomAsiganatura());


    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray jsonArrayA = new JSONArray();
    jsonArrayA.put(jsonObjectA);



    final JSONObject jsonObjectT = new JSONObject();
    try{

        jsonObjectT.put("idAsignatura", jsonArrayA);
        jsonObjectT.put("idEstudiante",jsonArrayE);
        jsonObjectT.put("nombreTarea", t.getNombreTarea());
        jsonObjectT.put("tareaNota", t.getTareaNota());

    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObjectT,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(ControlTareas.this, "Registro correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(ControlTareas.this, "Ocurrió un error al enviar la información", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    queue.add(request);


}
```

}

**// SOLUCION2 ( Propuesta por David)**
 @Override

public void onAgregaTarea(Tareas t) {

```
    // Objeto json de tipo String
    String jsonString = "{\n" +
            "        \"idAsignatura\": {\n" +
            "            \"idAsignatura\":" +t.getIdAsignatura().getIdAsignatura()+ ",\n" +
            "            \"nombreAsignatura\": \"" +t.getIdAsignatura().getNomAsiganatura()+ "\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"idEstudiante\": {\n" +
            "            \"idEstudiante\":" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdEstudiante()+ ",\n" +
            "            \"idUsuario\": {\n" +
            "                \"emailUsuario\": \"" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getEmailUsuario()+ "\",\n" +
            "                \"idUsuario\":" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getIdUsario()+ ",\n" +
            "                \"nombreUsuario\": \"" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getNombreUsuario()+ "\",\n" +
            "                \"pwdUsuario\": \"" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getPwdUsuario()+ "\",\n" +
            "                \"rolUsuario\": \"" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getRolUsuario()+ "\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            \"matriculado\":" +t.getIdEstudiante().getMatriculado()+ "\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"idTareas\":" +t.getIdTareas()+ ",\n" +
            "        \"nombreTarea\": \"" +t.getNombreTarea()+ "\",\n" +
            "        \"tareaNota\":" +t.getTareaNota()+ "\n" +
            "    }";


    // Objeto json de tipo JSONObject
    JSONObject jsonObjectT = null;

    try {

        jsonObjectT = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObjectT,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(ControlTareas.this, "Se envió correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(ControlTareas.this, "Ocurrió un error al enviar la información", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    queue.add(request);


}
```

}

// RESULTADO:

//Aunque agrega el objeto a la base de datos me lanza la siguiente excepción:

**com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
                                                                         at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)
                                                                         at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)
                                                                      Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:156)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                                         at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:68)
                                                                         at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)**

**Encontré  la solución a  este ultimo problema:**
En la clase ***com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest***;

Este método:

@Override

```
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}
```

hay que cambiarle el código  para que quede así:

@Override

```
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));

        JSONObject result = null;

        if (jsonString != null && jsonString.length() > 0)
            result = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        return Response.success(result,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}
```

Con esto se da por solucionado el problema. Gracias

Comment: queres mapear ese Json contra una clase ?

Comment: El problema es que el servidor no esta enviando una respuesta o la esta enviando nula, tal como explican [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104423/volley-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character-0-of).

Comment: Ya has encontrado tu respuesta pero como opinión personal, te recomendaría usar retrofit 2 y no voley, por el tema de la velocidad
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-and-volley

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo mio , adaptalo al tuyo

```
public void invocacionDibujadorMovimientos(final String URLDibujadorParametro, final Context context, String  request, final Response.Listener<GenericPtsResponseMovimientos> listener, final Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    int method = Request.Method.POST;

    String serviceURL = URLDibujador+URLDibujadorParametro;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String req = "";
    try {
        req = request;
        //RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, gethttpsUrlConnection(context, null));
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, null);
        objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(method, serviceURL, GenericPtsResponseMovimientos.class, req, listener, errorListener);
        objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(timeOut, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(objectRequest);
        // } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        //     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

GenericPtsResponse

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GenericPtsResponseMovimientos {

private int errorCode;
private String msg;
private String token;
private List<DataMovimientos> data;


public GenericPtsResponseMovimientos() {
    this.data = new ArrayList<>() ;
}

public GenericPtsResponseMovimientos(int errorCode, String msg, String token, List<DataMovimientos> data) {
    this();
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
    this.msg = msg;
    this.token = token;
    this.data = data;
}

public int getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}

public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public List<DataMovimientos> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<DataMovimientos> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

Clase DataMovimientos

```
public class DataMovimientos {

@JsonProperty("PaymentOrderID")
private String paymentOrderID;

@JsonProperty("ReferenciaNegocioOrd")
private String referenciaNegocioOrd;

@JsonProperty("ReferenciaCanalOrd")
private String referenciaCanalOrd;

@JsonProperty("ReferenciaNegocioBenef")
private String referenciaNegocioBenef;

@JsonProperty("ReferenciaCanalBenef")
private String referenciaCanalBenef;

@JsonProperty("BancoOrdenante")
private String bancoOrdenante;

@JsonProperty("BancoBeneficiario")
private String bancoBeneficiario;

@JsonProperty("CanalEntrada")
private String canalEntrada;

@JsonProperty("TipoCuentaOrd")
private String tipoCuentaOrd;

@JsonProperty("SucursalBancoOrd")
private String sucursalBancoOrd;

@JsonProperty("MonedaBancoOrd")
private String monedaBancoOrd;

@JsonProperty("NumeroCuentaOrd")
private String numeroCuentaOrd;

@JsonProperty("ImporteOrd")
private String importeOrd;

@JsonProperty("TipoCuentaBenef")
private String tipoCuentaBenef;

@JsonProperty("SucursalBancoBenef")
private String sucursalBancoBenef;

@JsonProperty("MonedaBancoBenef")
private String monedaBancoBenef;

@JsonProperty("NumeroCuentaBenef")
private String numeroCuentaBenef;

@JsonProperty("ImporteBenef")
private String importeBenef;

@JsonProperty("MonedaTransaccion")
private String monedaTransaccion;

@JsonProperty("ImporteTransaccion")
private String importeTransaccion;

@JsonProperty("EstadoInterno")
private String estadoInterno;

@JsonProperty("EstadoCanal")
private String estadoCanal;

@JsonProperty("Time")
private String time;
@JsonProperty("TransactionType")
private String transactionType;

@JsonProperty("Referencia")
private String referencia;


public String getTransactionType() {
    return transactionType;
}

public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
}

public DataMovimientos(String paymentOrderID, String referenciaNegocioOrd, String referenciaCanalOrd, String referenciaNegocioBenef, String referenciaCanalBenef, String bancoOrdenante, String bancoBeneficiario, String canalEntrada, String tipoCuentaOrd, String sucursalBancoOrd, String monedaBancoOrd, String numeroCuentaOrd, String importeOrd, String tipoCuentaBenef, String sucursalBancoBenef, String monedaBancoBenef, String numeroCuentaBenef, String importeBenef, String monedaTransaccion, String importeTransaccion, String estadoInterno, String estadoCanal, String time,String transactionType,String referencia) {
    this.referencia= referencia;
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
    this.paymentOrderID = paymentOrderID;
    this.referenciaNegocioOrd = referenciaNegocioOrd;
    this.referenciaCanalOrd = referenciaCanalOrd;
    this.referenciaNegocioBenef = referenciaNegocioBenef;
    this.referenciaCanalBenef = referenciaCanalBenef;
    this.bancoOrdenante = bancoOrdenante;
    this.bancoBeneficiario = bancoBeneficiario;
    this.canalEntrada = canalEntrada;
    this.tipoCuentaOrd = tipoCuentaOrd;
    this.sucursalBancoOrd = sucursalBancoOrd;
    this.monedaBancoOrd = monedaBancoOrd;
    this.numeroCuentaOrd = numeroCuentaOrd;
    this.importeOrd = importeOrd;
    this.tipoCuentaBenef = tipoCuentaBenef;
    this.sucursalBancoBenef = sucursalBancoBenef;
    this.monedaBancoBenef = monedaBancoBenef;
    this.numeroCuentaBenef = numeroCuentaBenef;
    this.importeBenef = importeBenef;
    this.monedaTransaccion = monedaTransaccion;
    this.importeTransaccion = importeTransaccion;
    this.estadoInterno = estadoInterno;
    this.estadoCanal = estadoCanal;
    this.time = time;
}
public DataMovimientos(){

}

public String getReferencia() {
    return referencia;
}

public void setReferencia(String referencia) {
    this.referencia = referencia;
}

public String getPaymentOrderID() {
    return paymentOrderID;
}

public void setPaymentOrderID(String paymentOrderID) {
    this.paymentOrderID = paymentOrderID;
}

public String getReferenciaNegocioOrd() {
    return referenciaNegocioOrd;
}

public void setReferenciaNegocioOrd(String referenciaNegocioOrd) {
    this.referenciaNegocioOrd = referenciaNegocioOrd;
}

public String getReferenciaCanalOrd() {
    return referenciaCanalOrd;
}

public void setReferenciaCanalOrd(String referenciaCanalOrd) {
    this.referenciaCanalOrd = referenciaCanalOrd;
}

public String getReferenciaNegocioBenef() {
    return referenciaNegocioBenef;
}

public void setReferenciaNegocioBenef(String referenciaNegocioBenef) {
    this.referenciaNegocioBenef = referenciaNegocioBenef;
}

public String getReferenciaCanalBenef() {
    return referenciaCanalBenef;
}

public void setReferenciaCanalBenef(String referenciaCanalBenef) {
    this.referenciaCanalBenef = referenciaCanalBenef;
}

public String getBancoOrdenante() {
    return bancoOrdenante;
}

public void setBancoOrdenante(String bancoOrdenante) {
    this.bancoOrdenante = bancoOrdenante;
}

public String getBancoBeneficiario() {
    return bancoBeneficiario;
}

public void setBancoBeneficiario(String bancoBeneficiario) {
    this.bancoBeneficiario = bancoBeneficiario;
}

public String getCanalEntrada() {
    return canalEntrada;
}

public void setCanalEntrada(String canalEntrada) {
    this.canalEntrada = canalEntrada;
}

public String getTipoCuentaOrd() {
    return tipoCuentaOrd;
}

public void setTipoCuentaOrd(String tipoCuentaOrd) {
    this.tipoCuentaOrd = tipoCuentaOrd;
}

public String getSucursalBancoOrd() {
    return sucursalBancoOrd;
}

public void setSucursalBancoOrd(String sucursalBancoOrd) {
    this.sucursalBancoOrd = sucursalBancoOrd;
}

public String getMonedaBancoOrd() {
    return monedaBancoOrd;
}

public void setMonedaBancoOrd(String monedaBancoOrd) {
    this.monedaBancoOrd = monedaBancoOrd;
}

public String getNumeroCuentaOrd() {
    return numeroCuentaOrd;
}

public void setNumeroCuentaOrd(String numeroCuentaOrd) {
    this.numeroCuentaOrd = numeroCuentaOrd;
}

public String getImporteOrd() {
    return importeOrd;
}

public void setImporteOrd(String importeOrd) {
    this.importeOrd = importeOrd;
}

public String getTipoCuentaBenef() {
    return tipoCuentaBenef;
}

public void setTipoCuentaBenef(String tipoCuentaBenef) {
    this.tipoCuentaBenef = tipoCuentaBenef;
}

public String getSucursalBancoBenef() {
    return sucursalBancoBenef;
}

public void setSucursalBancoBenef(String sucursalBancoBenef) {
    this.sucursalBancoBenef = sucursalBancoBenef;
}

public String getMonedaBancoBenef() {
    return monedaBancoBenef;
}

public void setMonedaBancoBenef(String monedaBancoBenef) {
    this.monedaBancoBenef = monedaBancoBenef;
}

public String getNumeroCuentaBenef() {
    return numeroCuentaBenef;
}

public void setNumeroCuentaBenef(String numeroCuentaBenef) {
    this.numeroCuentaBenef = numeroCuentaBenef;
}

public String getImporteBenef() {
    return importeBenef;
}

public void setImporteBenef(String importeBenef) {
    this.importeBenef = importeBenef;
}

public String getMonedaTransaccion() {
    return monedaTransaccion;
}

public void setMonedaTransaccion(String monedaTransaccion) {
    this.monedaTransaccion = monedaTransaccion;
}

public String getImporteTransaccion() {
    return importeTransaccion;
}

public void setImporteTransaccion(String importeTransaccion) {
    this.importeTransaccion = importeTransaccion;
}

public String getEstadoInterno() {
    return estadoInterno;
}

public void setEstadoInterno(String estadoInterno) {
    this.estadoInterno = estadoInterno;
}

public String getEstadoCanal() {
    return estadoCanal;
}

public void setEstadoCanal(String estadoCanal) {
    this.estadoCanal = estadoCanal;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
```

mi Json es:

```
{
  "errorCode": "0",
  "msg": "",
  "token": "3ec2c554-c577-472a-993d-da4dea6d91b2",
  "data": [
    {
      "PaymentOrderID": "10527",
      "ReferenciaNegocioOrd": "",
      "ReferenciaCanalOrd": "",
      "ReferenciaNegocioBenef": "60428022-5e00-4461-b",
      "ReferenciaCanalBenef": "26916f26-5e92-49b8-8fbe-ddc59ee971c3",
      "BancoOrdenante": "10001",
      "BancoBeneficiario": "10001",
      "CanalEntrada": "MOBILE",
      "TipoCuentaOrd": "CA",
      "SucursalBancoOrd": "",
      "MonedaBancoOrd": "MXN",
      "NumeroCuentaOrd": "938584",
      "ImporteOrd": "2.000",
      "TipoCuentaBenef": "CA",
      "SucursalBancoBenef": "",
      "MonedaBancoBenef": "MXN",
      "NumeroCuentaBenef": "5435",
      "ImporteBenef": "2.000",
      "MonedaTransaccion": "MXN",
      "ImporteTransaccion": "2.00",
      "EstadoInterno": "SETTLEMENT",
      "EstadoCanal": "",
      "Time": "2017-09-11 14:48:39.050",
      "TransactionType": "DO-IT-OA-1C-D-P"
    },
    {
      "PaymentOrderID": "10526",
      "ReferenciaNegocioOrd": "",
      "ReferenciaCanalOrd": "",
      "ReferenciaNegocioBenef": "60428022-5e00-4461-b",
      "ReferenciaCanalBenef": "2591b375-437a-40bf-be42-970d3152dbf3",
      "BancoOrdenante": "10001",
      "BancoBeneficiario": "10001",
      "CanalEntrada": "MOBILE",
      "TipoCuentaOrd": "CA",
      "SucursalBancoOrd": "",
      "MonedaBancoOrd": "MXN",
      "NumeroCuentaOrd": "938584",
      "ImporteOrd": "2.000",
      "TipoCuentaBenef": "CA",
      "SucursalBancoBenef": "",
      "MonedaBancoBenef": "MXN",
      "NumeroCuentaBenef": "5435",
      "ImporteBenef": "2.000",
      "MonedaTransaccion": "MXN",
      "ImporteTransaccion": "2.00",
      "EstadoInterno": "SETTLEMENT",
      "EstadoCanal": "",
      "Time": "2017-09-11 14:48:19.767",
      "TransactionType": "DO-IT-OA-1C-D-P"
    },
    {
      "PaymentOrderID": "10524",
      "ReferenciaNegocioOrd": "",
      "ReferenciaCanalOrd": "",
      "ReferenciaNegocioBenef": "60428022-5e00-4461-b",
      "ReferenciaCanalBenef": "d9428852-1d9d-47b8-b80d-8f9e697bc0a8",
      "BancoOrdenante": "10001",
      "BancoBeneficiario": "10001",
      "CanalEntrada": "MOBILE",
      "TipoCuentaOrd": "CA",
      "SucursalBancoOrd": "",
      "MonedaBancoOrd": "MXN",
      "NumeroCuentaOrd": "100000000000009",
      "ImporteOrd": "25.000",
      "TipoCuentaBenef": "CA",
      "SucursalBancoBenef": "",
      "MonedaBancoBenef": "MXN",
      "NumeroCuentaBenef": "938584",
      "ImporteBenef": "25.000",
      "MonedaTransaccion": "MXN",
      "ImporteTransaccion": "25.00",
      "EstadoInterno": "SETTLEMENT",
      "EstadoCanal": "",
      "Time": "2017-09-11 12:34:37.793",
      "TransactionType": "WALLETTOACC.DO-LW-TA-1C-D-P"
    },
    {
      "PaymentOrderID": "10523",
      "ReferenciaNegocioOrd": "",
      "ReferenciaCanalOrd": "",
      "ReferenciaNegocioBenef": "60428022-5e00-4461-b",
      "ReferenciaCanalBenef": "b15b5c83-54cc-4a01-94d4-f13831dad2fe",
      "BancoOrdenante": "10001",
      "BancoBeneficiario": "10001",
      "CanalEntrada": "MOBILE",
      "TipoCuentaOrd": "CA",
      "SucursalBancoOrd": "",
      "MonedaBancoOrd": "MXN",
      "NumeroCuentaOrd": "100000000000009",
      "ImporteOrd": "25.000",
      "TipoCuentaBenef": "CA",
      "SucursalBancoBenef": "",
      "MonedaBancoBenef": "MXN",
      "NumeroCuentaBenef": "938584",
      "ImporteBenef": "25.000",
      "MonedaTransaccion": "MXN",
      "ImporteTransaccion": "25.00",
      "EstadoInterno": "SETTLEMENT",
      "EstadoCanal": "",
      "Time": "2017-09-11 12:34:36.630",
      "TransactionType": "WALLETTOACC.DO-LW-TA-1C-D-P"
    },
    {
      "PaymentOrderID": "10520",
      "ReferenciaNegocioOrd": "",
      "ReferenciaCanalOrd": "",
      "ReferenciaNegocioBenef": "60428022-5e00-4461-b",
      "ReferenciaCanalBenef": "4b8ceb0c-ba7f-4b95-a2d6-a3d630728a7a",
      "BancoOrdenante": "10001",
      "BancoBeneficiario": "10001",
      "CanalEntrada": "MOBILE",
      "TipoCuentaOrd": "CA",
      "SucursalBancoOrd": "",
      "MonedaBancoOrd": "MXN",
      "NumeroCuentaOrd": "938584",
      "ImporteOrd": "2.000",
      "TipoCuentaBenef": "CA",
      "SucursalBancoBenef": "",
      "MonedaBancoBenef": "MXN",
      "NumeroCuentaBenef": "5435",
      "ImporteBenef": "2.000",
      "MonedaTransaccion": "MXN",
      "ImporteTransaccion": "2.00",
      "EstadoInterno": "SETTLEMENT",
      "EstadoCanal": "",
      "Time": "2017-09-11 10:17:48.127",
      "TransactionType": "DO-IT-OA-1C-D-P"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Utiliza http://jsonprettyprint.com/ para dar un formato legible al JSON. Saludos :D

Comment: prefiero http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: O http://jsbeautifier.org/ +@fredyfx

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag buena voz! Entonces siguientes preguntas y/o respuestas, les pasas un bonito formato al código Json :D Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Es mas fácil si guardas el objeto json en un `String` y luego lo conviertes a un `JSONObject`, el cual es el que utilizaras en el `request`.

Para convertir un objeto json `String` a un objeto json `JSONObject` es tan fácil como pasar el objeto json `String` como parámetro a la instancia del objeto `JSONObject`.

```
public void onAgregaTarea(Tareas t) {

    // Objeto json de tipo String
    String jsonString = "{\n" +
            "        \"idAsignatura\": {\n" +
            "            \"idAsignatura\":" +t.getIdAsignatura().getIdAsignatura()+ ",\n" +
            "            \"nombreAsignatura\": \"" +t.getIdAsignatura().getNomAsiganatura()+ "\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"idEstudiante\": {\n" +
            "            \"idEstudiante\":" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdEstudiante()+ ",\n" +
            "            \"idUsuario\": {\n" +
            "                \"emailUsuario\": \"" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getEmailUsuario()+ "\",\n" +
            "                \"idUsuario\":" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getIdUsario()+ ",\n" +
            "                \"nombreUsuario\": \"" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getNombreUsuario()+ "\",\n" +
            "                \"pwdUsuario\": \"" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getPwdUsuario()+ "\",\n" +
            "                \"rolUsuario\": \"" +t.getIdEstudiante().getIdUsuario().getRolUsuario()+ "\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            \"matriculado\":" +t.getIdEstudiante().getMatriculado()+ "\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"idTareas\":" +t.getIdTarea()+ ",\n" +
            "        \"nombreTarea\": \"" +t.getNombreTarea()+ "\",\n" +
            "        \"tareaNota\":" +t.getTareaNota()+ "\n" +
            "    }";


    // Objeto json de tipo JSONObject
    JSONObject jsonObjectT = null;

    try {

        jsonObjectT = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObjectT,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(ControlTareas.this, "Se envió correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, 
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(ControlTareas.this, "Ocurrió un error al enviar la información", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    });

    queue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Me agrega el objeto, pero me lanza esta excepcion: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
                                                                         at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)
                                                                     com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:68) ...

Comment: Ese error te lo daba antes?

Comment: No, solo con peticiones de objetos Json anidados.